# .NET MVC 3: Form Doesn't Submit After JQuery Code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, form-submit

I have a simple form with two fields and an optional field which is showed when a checkbox is selected and hidden if the checkbox is not selected - the show/hide is controlled by jQuery. The problem is that when the page is loaded first time the form is submitted as usual but once  the checkbox is checked or unchecked the submit button does not submit the form or even more weird it does nothing.

I have a strongly-typed view with model:

```
@model Metteem.ViewModels.SchedularAccount
```

And my simple script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#showhide").click(function () {
        $("#alternatingInput").toggle('fast');
    });
});
</script>
```

Where the code of the form is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { Class = "well form-horizontal" }))
{
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Meeting ID</label>
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MeetingId, new { Class = "input-xlarge" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MeetingId, null, new { Class = "help-inline" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { Class = "input-xlarge" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, null, new { Class = "help-inline" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Login as Host?</label>
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsHost, new { Class = "input-xlarge", id = "showhide" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" id="alternatingInput" style="display: block; ">
            <label class="control-label">Participant ID</label>
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserId, new { Class = "input-xlarge", Value = "0" })
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-actions">
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Home", null, new { Class = "btn" })
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </div>
}
```

In my action I have an HttpPost attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult HostParticipantLogin(SchedularAccount account)
{
   //Rest of my code
}
```

What can be go wrong?

Comment: Have you enabled client side validation?

Comment: shouldn't the button be a submit button ? i.e `<input type=submit class="btn btn-primary" Value="Login" />` ?

Comment: @gdoron Firebug doesn't give any clues unfortunately, the only change is that display option is block when the checkbox is unchecked and none when it is checked: `<div class="control-group" id="alternatingInput" style="display: block; "></div>`

Comment: @DarinDimitrov yes, the client side validation is enabled. Though it doesn't matter because it is not because of the empty hidden textbox, if it was filled the sitution doesn't change.

Comment: @keshav it is possible to use such a method but using a button is also ok, on my other pages this works with no problem.

Comment: Try `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">` if you have to use a `<button>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @avesse, adding type as submit solves the problem..

> Try `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">` if you have to use
>   a `<button>` element.